# how can i display a list of selected checkboxes in an alert dialog?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-alertdialog

am trying to properly display a list of selected checkboxes stored in an array and display them as a list in an alert dialog.

```
if(registeredCourseList.getcoursessize() <= 5){
    System.out.println(registeredCourseList.getCoursesArray());

    // setup the alert builder
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Are you sure you want to register the following courses? ");

    // add a checkbox list
    String[] courses ={String.valueOf(registeredCourseList.getCourses().toString())};
    boolean[] checkedItems = {true, true, true, true, true};
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(courses, checkedItems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
             // user checked or unchecked a box
         }
    });

    // add OK and Cancel buttons
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              // user clicked OK
              // send the map or array to the server
              try {
                   processRegistration(mView,registeredCourseList.getCoursesArray());
              } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
              }

              Context context = getApplicationContext();
              CharSequence text = "Registered Courses Successfully";
              int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

              Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
              toast.show();

              onBackPressed();
          }
      });
      builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

      // create and show the alert dialog
      AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
      dialog.show();

 } else {

       Context context = getApplicationContext();
       CharSequence text = "Choose at least 5 courses";
       int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

       Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
       toast.show();

       //back to the reg activity
       // onBackPressed();
 }
```

i can get the courses but they display and an array object. i want to display the courses as a list of checkeboxes in the alert dialog.

Comment: What is the exact problem? like are you not able to show list view or no able to get selected check boxes. Please elaborate your problem ?

Comment: i can get the courses but they dont display as checkboxs. e.g {maths,english,science,bio}. i want them to display as a checkbox list

Comment: Are you sure there will be 5 selected courses always?

Comment: Your if statement shows size of `registeredCourseList` can be smaller than 5 , but your `checkedItems` is fixed to size 5.

Comment: even less than 5 will display. the format of displaying is whats wrong. i want it to display as a checkbox list instead of the current output am getting which is {maths,english,science,bio}

Comment: am only getting one checkbox with all the courses selected

Answer (score 0):

[image] I have checked your code like this

```
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Are you sure you want to register the following courses? ");

    // add a checkbox list
    String[] courses ={"acx","sadsa","ksk","ksj","ywtgd"};
    boolean[] checkedItems = {true, true, true, true, true};
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(courses, checkedItems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
            // user checked or unchecked a box
        }
    });
    builder.show();
```

and it is showing five different checkboxes. Check your `String[] courses ={String.valueOf(registeredCourseList.getCourses().toString())};`
I guess output of this line is all String  Data at 0 index instead of showing on different indexes.
**So instead of using above line Use for loop to insert values inside array**

**Edited for FOR Loop**
Just an Example

```
  ArrayList courses=new ArrayList();
    for(int i=0;i<registeredCourseList.size;i++){
        courses.add(registeredCourseList.get(i).getCourses());
    }
```

Try something like this

Comment: can you help me with the code  for a loop to insert values inside array? am new to this

Comment: am getting the courses from another another intent which are stored in registeredCourseList. so i dont want to initialize the courses in advance because the courses differ for every student

Comment: I am just giving you idea. The problem is in the way you are storing list items into array. Focus on that and search for that.there are multiple ways to achieve result